# Flutter Datatable - Empty container slowing loading time

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building an app where family details - divided into 3 sections - are displayed into 3 different data tables on the same page. The issue is before loading the page which will display the 3 data tables, an exception was caught, after which the page will load and display the 3 data tables properly with the correct data as well.

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building SecondPage(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _SecondPageState#eba94):
The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map<DataRow>(Closure: (AdultDetails) => DataRow)

The relevant error-causing widget was
    SecondPage
```

Code having widget SecondPage:

```
 children:<Widget>[
                  Container(
                      height: 50,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                            child: OutlineButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                         SecondPage(widget.familyRef)),
                                  );
                                },
```

To hide the exception, I passed empty containers to each data tables.

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  //final String adultid;
  final String familyRef;

  SecondPage(this.familyRef);
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}
...
Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: FittedBox(
                child: DataTable(
                  headingRowHeight: 50,
                  dataRowHeight: 50,
                  //columnSpacing: 10,
                  dividerThickness: 1,
                  columns: [
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        "First Name",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                      numeric: false,
                      tooltip: "",
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Center(
                          child: Text(
                        "Update",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      )),
                      numeric: false,
                      tooltip: "",
                    ),
                  ],
          rows: list1?.map(
                      (item) => DataRow(cells: [
                        DataCell(
                          Text(item.pensionerName.toString()),
                        ),

                       DataCell(OutlineButton(
                            child: Text("Update"),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => UpdateAdult(
                                      widget.familyRef,
                                      item.adultid,
                                      ));
                              Navigator.push(context, route);
                            },
                          ))
                        ]),
                    )?.toList() ?? [],
              ),
```

It worked for me - The *The method 'map' was called on null.* error screen does not show up but now each data table takes around 3 secs to load. What can I do to improve the loading performance? Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary condition

Example:

```
list1 == null ? Container() : list1?.map(
                      (item) => DataRow(cells: [
                        DataCell(
                          Text(item.pensionerName.toString()),
                        ),

                       ...

                    )?.toList() ?? [],
              ),
```

Comment: It gives me the following error and then loads the 3 data tables without any delay:


```════════ Exception caught by widgets library═══════════════════════════════════
type 'Container' is not a subtype of type 'List<DataRow>'
The relevant error-causing widget was 
SecondPage

```

Comment: the error itself says you don't require to ternary operator inside  rows: , but as a outside widget

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Can you be more clear how to use it as an outside widget? Below is the error-causing widget. Grateful if you could advise!
```MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            SecondPage(widget.familyRef)),
                                  );```

Comment: You need to show more code, by this I can't help you much